# Gettin ZeroMQ working with LISP in Windows

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, zeromq

Has anyone gotten `ZeroMQ` working with LISP in Windows?

I'm using `LispBox 0.7`

I have installed `ZeroMQ`.

1. **`(ql:quickload "zeromq")`**

> ```
> Unable to load foreign library (ZEROMQ).
> Error opening shared library libzmq.dll: The specified module could not be found.
>      [Condition of type CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY-ERROR]
> ```

2. **Add** the `libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll` dll to the `lispbox` folder,
   **edit** it's name to `libzmq.dll` and
   **call** **`(ql:quickload "zeromq")`** again.

> ```
> Unable to load foreign library (ZEROMQ).
> Error opening shared library libzmq.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>       [Condition of type CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY-ERROR]
> ```

Any idea how to get this up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

I was using the wrong library. Switching to 64 bit version fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the directory where  your dll is located appears in your PATH environment variable. You can set the PATH variable in the System control panel. You should probably reboot after setting it, so your lisp picks up the changes.